# How to build multiple complex nested objects from a database request result set?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, zend-db, data-objects

I'm working on a Zend Framework 2 application with a complex class (`Foo`) having many levels of nesting (`Foo.Bar`, `Foo.Baz.Buz` etc.). The data is stored in a relational database (MySQL). On the application level it gets `hydrate`ed to `DataObject`s by the `Zend\Hydrator\ClassMethods`.

To get all the data needed to build a `Foo` `DataObject` I use an SQL statement (wrapped by [`Zend\Db\Sql\Select`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/Select.php)). As `ResultSet` I get a big table like this:

```
id some_foo_attr bar_id some_bar_attr baz_id some_baz_attr buz_id some_buz_attr
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  foo_value_a   1      bar_value_a   1      baz_value_a   1      buz_value_a
1  foo_value_a   1      bar_value_a   1      baz_value_a   2      buz_value_b
1  foo_value_a   1      bar_value_a   2      baz_value_b   3      buz_value_c
1  foo_value_a   1      bar_value_a   2      baz_value_b   4      buz_value_d
1  foo_value_a   2      bar_value_b   3      baz_value_c   6      buz_value_e
1  foo_value_a   2      bar_value_b   3      baz_value_c   7      buz_value_f
1  foo_value_a   2      bar_value_b   4      baz_value_d   8      buz_value_g
1  foo_value_a   2      bar_value_b   4      baz_value_d   8      buz_value_h
2  foo_value_b   3      bar_value_c   5      baz_value_e   9      buz_value_i
...
```

Now I have a problem to get this data to `DataObject`s. What is an efficient way to do this? Or maybe I made a mistake a step before and should retrieve the data differently?